# Get the token usage from semantic kernel C#

Tags: c#, azure-openai, semantic-kernel

I am trying out the [semantic kernel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/semantic-kernel/overview/) in C# for a project. I am using the ChatCompletionService with Azure OpenAI and a few simple plugins that I created. I am not able to figure out how to get the token usage for a query. Any help would be appreciated. For example, in this [solution](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/semantic-kernel-docs/tree/main/samples/dotnet/08-Creating-Functions-For-AI) that microsoft has, is there a way to get the token usage after each question (GetStreamingChatMessageContentsAsync)? One [link](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/semantic-kernel/unlock-the-power-of-telemetry-in-semantic-kernel-sdk/) I found was about logging in open telmetry standard. But it does not log the token usage. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the [solution link](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/semantic-kernel-docs/tree/main/samples/dotnet/08-Creating-Functions-For-AI) you referenced in your question, one possible way to get this information is by making use of [`Metadata`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.semantickernel.functionresult.metadata?view=semantic-kernel-dotnet) property of [`FunctionResult`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.semantickernel.functionresult?view=semantic-kernel-dotnet). Token information is contained in `Usage` key in there which is of type [`CompletionsUsage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.ai.openai.completionsusage?view=azure-dotnet-preview&viewFallbackFrom=netstandard-2.0).

Your code would be something like:

```
var result = await kernel.InvokeAsync(function-to-invoke)
var metadata = result.Metadata
if (metadata.ContainsKey("Usage"))
{
    var usage = (CompletionsUsage)metadata["Usage"];
    Console.WriteLine($"Token usage. Input tokens: {usage.PromptTokens}; Output tokens: {usage.CompletionTokens}");
}
```

Please note that this information is not available just yet for streaming responses. For more details, please see this issue on GitHub: https://github.com/microsoft/semantic-kernel/issues/4691.

Comment: Thank you. I tried and it did not work. Apparently the GetStreamingChatMessageContentsAsync does not support getting token usage. We can only check the azure portal for the token usage when using GetStreamingChatMessageContentsAsync.

Comment: Please see my comment here: https://github.com/microsoft/semantic-kernel/issues/4691#issuecomment-1925784937. This is how I ended up getting token usage for streaming response.